# How can i store chat offline in Android

Tags: android, socket.io, android-volley, offline-caching, offline-storage

I am using Socket.io for sends and receives messages. I want to store the Chatting history among the users.

What is the best possible way to maintain the chat history and any snippets will be of great help.

Comment: i feel sq lite database!

Answer (score 0):

You can store it in local database link **SQLite** or **Android Room**.

You can follow this reference link for integrating **Android Room**  : https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/adding-components.html

Use this reference link for **SQLite** :  https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/sqlite.html

Thanks.

Comment: can you provide any example link for store  offline chat  in Android Room

Answer (score 0):

You can either write to a **file** and load from their when required. Or the other way around would be to use **SQLite** database to store the messages on the individual device.